# Handle multiple buttons from custom view in the main activity

Tags: java, android

I don't understand how I am able to access the buttons in a custom view from my main activity class.
I've got two classes:

1. MyActivity (Activity)
2. ButtonView (LinearLayout)

the ButtonView custom class contains multiple buttons that get added programmatically

```
addView(new Button(getContext()));
```

Now I would like to handle the onClickListener() method for each button, but in the MyActivity class.
There I've got something like

```
ButtonView  = (ButtonView)findViewById(R.id.button_view);
```

So when a button in the ButtonView gets pressed, a specific method should be called in the main activity class. I don't know how to achieve this, are there any suggestions?

Comment: are you adding the buttons programmatically in the MainActivity?

Comment: the buttons are being added programmatically in the ButtonView class itself

Answer (score 0):

```
public interface ButtonListener {
          public void onButtonPressed(View v);
```

ButtonView Class

```
ButtonListener mListener;
public void setListener(ButtonListener listener) { mListener = listener; }

Button button = new Button(getContext());
button.setOnClickListener(  ..... if(mListener != null { mListener.onButtonPressed(v));
addView(button);
```

Activity Class

```
  public MainActivity extends Activity implements ButtonListener {

          ButtonView buttons = new ButtonView();
          buttons.setListener(this);
          public void onButtonPressed(View v) { //your code here to handle button pressed }


  }
```

basiclly when your press any button in the ButtonView Class it will send using the Listener to the Activity the Button View itself.

Hope it helps.

Comment: What do these first two lines mean? Thanks for the response

Comment: Interface class which is the listener itself.